# How can I Implement a mechanism for request authentication for specific endpoints using JWT with Retrofit.?

Tags: android, authentication, jwt, retrofit, access-token

1. How can I Implement a mechanism for request authentication for specific endpoints using JWT with Retrofit. Please note that not all the requests are authenticated, but it should be possible to somehow specify if the request should contain an authentication token or no. 2. How to implement token renewal? A server returns HTTP status code 300 in case of expired token and a new token can be requested with current (expired) JWT token. The implemented solution should be reusable

Comment: You should separate your question into 2 different questions, I think.
For example: 
1. How can I Implement a mechanism for request authentication for specific endpoints using JWT with Retrofit. Please note that not all the requests are authenticated, but it should be possible to somehow specify if the request should contain an authentication token or no.

2. How to implement token renewal? A server returns HTTP status code 300 in case of expired token and a new token can be requested with current (expired) JWT token. The implemented solution should be reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I had to attempt this at work for a maybe project and I came up with two solutions, but ill post one.

What I ended up doing was creating an interface that would provide all the required fields.

like below

```
interface IClient {

/**
 * Defines name of theClass (Used in shared preferences to make a store of creds)
 * @return String
 */
@NonNull
String getName();

/**
 * Defines endpoint for Redirection
 * @return String
 */
@NonNull String getState();

/**
 * Defines a URI to start a web view etc.
 * @return String
 */
@NonNull
Uri getIntentUri();


/**
 * Defines endpoint for Access token
 * @return Endpoint
 */
@NonNull EndPoint getTokenEndpoint();

/**
 * Defines endpoint for Access Code
 * @return Endpoint
 */
@NonNull EndPoint getAutenticationCodeEndPoint();

/**
 * Defines endpoint for getting the User Information
 * @return Endpoint
 */
@NonNull EndPoint getUserInfoEndpoint();

/**
 * Defines uri for Redirection
 * @return String
 */
@NonNull String getRedirectUri();

/**
 * Defines GrantType
 * @return GrantType
 */
@NonNull GrantType getGrantType();

/**
 * Defines clientId
 * @return String
 */
@NonNull String getClientId();

/**
 * Defines clientSecret
 * @return String
 */
@NonNull String getClientSecret();

/**
 * Defines scope
 * @return String
 */
@NonNull String getScope();

@NonNull Class<?> logInActivity();

@NonNull Class<?> logOutActivity();

void logOut();

@LayoutRes int intermediaryLoginView();

void startLogin(Context context);

}
```

when then you implement that into a class

```
public class Client implements IClient {

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return "DEMO";
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Uri getIntentUri() {
        return Uri.parse("https://exampleurl" +
                "/authorize?client_id=" + getClientId() +
                "&scope=" + getScope() +
                "&state=" + getState() +
                "&redirect_uri=" + getRedirectUri() +
                "&response_type=code"
        );
    }


    @NotNull
    @Override
    public EndPoint getTokenEndpoint() {
        return new EndPoint("https://url", "token");
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public EndPoint getAutenticationCodeEndPoint() {
        return new EndPoint("https://url", "token");
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public EndPoint getUserInfoEndpoint() {
        return new EndPoint("https://url", "/api/me");
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public GrantType getGrantType() {
        return GrantType.authorization_code;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getClientId() {
        return "";
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getClientSecret() {
        return "";
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getRedirectUri() {
        return "example://oauth";
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getScope() {
        return "app.something.user";
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Class<?> logInActivity() {
        return MainActivity.class;
    }

    @LayoutRes
    @Override
    public int intermediaryLoginView(){
        return R.layout.logginin;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Class<?> logOutActivity() {
        return Loggedout.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void logOut() {

    }

    @Override
    public void startLogin(Context context){
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder customTabsIntentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        customTabsIntentBuilder.setShowTitle(false);
        customTabsIntentBuilder.enableUrlBarHiding();
        CustomTabsIntent intents = customTabsIntentBuilder.build();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),  getIntentUri().toString());
        intents.launchUrl(context, getIntentUri());
    }
}
```

The next part would really depend on how your implementation would be.

I ended up creating an OAuth manager class

```
 public class OAuthManager {
    
        private IClient iClient;
        private static OAuthSharedPreferences mOAuthSharedPreferences;
        private static OAuthInterceptor mOAuthInterceptor;
    
        private InternalOAuth2Provider internalOAuth2Provider;
    
        private static Observable<AccessTokenResponse> tokenResponseObservable;
    
        RetrofitApi retrofitApi;
    
        public OAuthManager(InternalOAuth2Provider internalOAuth2Provider, IClient iClient, SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences) {
            this.iClient = iClient;
            this.internalOAuth2Provider = internalOAuth2Provider;
            mOAuthSharedPreferences = new OAuthSharedPreferences(mSharedPreferences);
            mOAuthInterceptor = new OAuthInterceptor(mOAuthSharedPreferences);
    
    
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                    .build();
    
            Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://this-is-replaced-regardless.com/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    
            retrofitApi = builder.create(RetrofitApi.class);
    
            initRefreshTokenObservable();//try to Refresh token immediately <-- log user in if needed
        }
    
        private void initRefreshTokenObservable() {
            tokenResponseObservable = Single.defer(this::refreshAccessToken)
                    .toObservable()
                    .share()
                    .doOnComplete(() -> internalOAuth2Provider.SuccessfulLogin());//<---TODO this or  mInternalOAuth2Provider.SuccessfulLogin(); ?????
    
        }
    
        private Single<AccessTokenResponse> refreshAccessToken() {
            return getRefreshToken()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnSuccess(
                            accessTokenResponse -> mOAuthSharedPreferences.UpdateOAuthCredentials(accessTokenResponse)
                    ).doOnError(throwable -> {
                        if (OAuthAuthenticationErrorHandler.invalidRefreshToken(throwable)) {
                            logOut();
                        }
                    });
        }
    
    
        void logOut(){
            if(mOAuthSharedPreferences.logout()){
                internalOAuth2Provider.SuccessfulLogout();
                return;
            }
            Log.d("OAuthManager - Internal", "Unable to clear the saved preferences");
        }
    
        static Observable<?> wrapWithOAuth(Observable<?> observable) {
            return observable.compose(observableTransformer());
        }
    
        static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> observableTransformer() {
            return upstream -> {
                upstream.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                    if (mOAuthSharedPreferences.isTokenExpired()) {
                        tokenResponseObservable.flatMap(accessTokenResponse -> upstream);
                    } else {
                        upstream.onErrorResumeNext((Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<T>>) throwable1 -> {
                            if (OAuthAuthenticationErrorHandler.invalidAccessToken(throwable1)) {
                                tokenResponseObservable.flatMap(accessTokenResponse -> upstream);
                            } else {
                                return Observable.error(throwable1);
                            }
                            return null;
                        });
                    }
                });
                return null;
            };
        }
    
        /**
         * Okhttp synchronous request to refresh token
         *
         * @return Single<AccessTokenResponse>
         */
        private Single<AccessTokenResponse> getRefreshToken() {
    
            if (mOAuthSharedPreferences.getRefreshToken().length() > 0 && mOAuthSharedPreferences.getExpirationTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) {
                return null;
            }
    
            RefreshTokenBody body = new RefreshTokenBody(
                    iClient.getClientId(),
                    iClient.getClientSecret(),
                    iClient.getGrantType().toString(),
                    mOAuthSharedPreferences.getRefreshToken()
            );
    
            return retrofitApi.refreshToken(iClient.getTokenEndpoint().getUri(), body);
        }
    
        /**
         * Okhttp synchronous request to refresh token
         *
         * @return Response
         */
        private Single<AccessTokenResponse> authenticateAuthorizationCode(String code) {
    
            if (mOAuthSharedPreferences.getRefreshToken().length() > 0 && mOAuthSharedPreferences.getExpirationTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) {
                return null;
            }
    
            return retrofitApi.authenticateAuthorizationCode2(iClient.getAutenticationCodeEndPoint().getUri(), iClient.getClientId(),
                    iClient.getClientSecret(),
                    code,
                    iClient.getGrantType().toString(),
                    iClient.getRedirectUri());
        }
    
        public void validateAuthorizationGrant(String code) {
            if (code == null || code.length() < 1) {
                return;
            }
            // Network Request to login
            authenticateAuthorizationCode(code).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnSuccess(accessTokenResponse -> internalOAuth2Provider.SuccessfulLogin())
                    .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                    .subscribe();
        }
    
        /**
         * Interceptor that adds Authorisation header with access token
         */
        public static OAuthInterceptor getOAuthInterceptor() {
            if (mOAuthInterceptor == null) {
                mOAuthInterceptor = new OAuthInterceptor(mOAuthSharedPreferences);
            }
            return mOAuthInterceptor;
        }
    }
```

In the Base app that extends Application I would create an instance of Internal OAuth Provider

```
    public class InternalOAuth2Provider {

    private static InternalOAuth2Provider _sInstance;

    public OkHttpClient client;
    public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    OAuthManager oAuthManager;

    private Context mContext;

    private IClient iClient;

    public synchronized static InternalOAuth2Provider getInstance(IClient iClient, Context context) {
        if (_sInstance == null) _sInstance = new InternalOAuth2Provider(iClient, context);
        return _sInstance;
    }

    protected InternalOAuth2Provider(IClient iClient, Context context) {
            client = new OkHttpClient();
            SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(iClient.getName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
            oAuthManager = new OAuthManager(this, iClient, mSharedPreferences);
            this.mContext = context;
            this.iClient = iClient;
            init();
            _sInstance = this;
    }

    protected void init() {
        List<PackageInfo> pInfos = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

        boolean loginClass = false;
        boolean logOutClass = false;

        for (PackageInfo pInfo : pInfos) {
            ActivityInfo[] aInfos = pInfo.activities;
            if (aInfos != null) {
                for (ActivityInfo activityInfo : aInfos) {
                    if (activityInfo.name.equals(iClient.logInActivity().getName())) {
                        loginClass = true;
                    }
                    if (activityInfo.name.equals(iClient.logOutActivity().getName())) {
                        logOutClass = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!loginClass || !logOutClass) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid return value Activity Class<" + (loginClass ? iClient.logOutActivity().getSimpleName() : iClient.logInActivity().getSimpleName()) + ".class> not found in Manifest");
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    public UserInfo getUserInformation() {
        try {
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create("", JSON);

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(
                            iClient.getUserInfoEndpoint().getUri()
                    )
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return parseResponseIntoUserInfo(response.body().string());
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public OAuthManager getoAuthManager() {
        return oAuthManager;
    }

    private UserInfo parseResponseIntoUserInfo(String responseBody) {
        return gson.fromJson(responseBody, UserInfo.class);
    }

    public void logOut(){
        oAuthManager.logOut();
    }

    public void SuccessfulLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, iClient.logInActivity());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void SuccessfulLogout() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, iClient.logOutActivity());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void getUriIntent(Uri data) {
        if (iClient.getGrantType() != authorization_code) {
            return;
        }
        if (data == null) {
            return;
        }
        String code = data.getQueryParameter("code") == null ? "" : data.getQueryParameter("code");

        //TODO is this the only one we receive URI data for?
        switch (iClient.getGrantType()) {
            case authorization_code:
                oAuthManager.validateAuthorizationGrant(code);
                break;
            case password_grant:
            case device_code:
            case PKCE:
            case client_credentials:
            default:
        }
    }

    public void Login(Context context){
        iClient.startLogin(context);
    }
}
```

If you are using Retrofit you need to provide an Interceptor, this will add the Bearer token to your requests

```
class OAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private OAuthSharedPreferences oAuthSharedPreferences;

    public OAuthInterceptor(OAuthSharedPreferences oAuthSharedPreferences) {
        this.oAuthSharedPreferences = oAuthSharedPreferences;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NotNull Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Request request = chain.request();
        Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(oAuthSharedPreferences.getAuthenticationToken())){
            String accessToken = oAuthSharedPreferences.getAuthenticationToken();
            builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

And then to wrap your calls and exclude ones that are not secured by OAuth I created a CallAdapterFactory (note I haven't implemented this myself yet)

```
class OAuthCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {

        Type rawReturnType = CallAdapter.Factory.getRawType(returnType);

        boolean ignored = false;

        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation instanceof AuthExempt) {
                ignored = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rawReturnType.equals(Completable.class)) {
            return new OAuthCallAdapter<Void>(Void.class, true, true, false, false, false, true, ignored);
        }

        boolean isFlowable = rawReturnType == Flowable.class;
        boolean isSingle = rawReturnType == Single.class;
        boolean isMaybe = rawReturnType == Maybe.class;

        if (rawReturnType != Observable.class && !isFlowable && !isSingle && !isMaybe) {
            return null;
        }
        boolean isBody = false;
        Type responseType;
        if (!(returnType instanceof ParameterizedType)) {

            throw new IllegalStateException(returnType.toString() + " return type must be parameterized"
                    + " as " + returnType.toString() + "<Foo> or " + returnType.toString() + "<? extends Foo>");

        }
        Type observableType = CallAdapter.Factory.getParameterUpperBound(0, (ParameterizedType)returnType);
        Type rawObservableType = CallAdapter.Factory.getRawType(observableType);
        if (rawObservableType == Response.class) {
            if (!(observableType instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Response must be parameterized as Response<Foo> or Response<? extends Foo>");
            }
            responseType = CallAdapter.Factory.getParameterUpperBound(0, (ParameterizedType)observableType);
        } else {
            responseType = observableType;
            isBody = true;
        }
        return new OAuthCallAdapter<>(responseType, true, isBody, isFlowable, isSingle, isMaybe, false, ignored);
    }
}
```

class OAuthCallAdapter implements CallAdapter<R, Object> {

```
private final Type responseType;
private final boolean isAsync;
private final boolean isBody;
private final boolean isFlowable;
private final boolean isSingle;
private final boolean isMaybe;
private final boolean isCompletable;
private final boolean ignoreAuth;

public OAuthCallAdapter(Type responseType, boolean isAsync, boolean isBody, boolean isFlowable, boolean isSingle, boolean isMaybe, boolean isCompletable, boolean ignoreAuth) {
    this.responseType = responseType;
    this.isAsync = isAsync;
    this.isBody = isBody;
    this.isFlowable = isFlowable;
    this.isSingle = isSingle;
    this.isMaybe = isMaybe;
    this.isCompletable = isCompletable;
    this.ignoreAuth = ignoreAuth;
}

@NotNull
@Override
public Type responseType() {
    return responseType;
}

@NotNull
@Override
public Object adapt(@NotNull Call<R> call) {
    Observable<Response<R>> responseObservable = isAsync
            ? new CallEnqueueObservable<>(call)
            : new CallExecuteObservable<>(call);

    Observable<?> observable;
    if (isBody) {
        observable = new BodyObservable<>(responseObservable);
    } else {
        observable = responseObservable;
    }

    if (!ignoreAuth) {
        observable = wrapWithOAuth(observable);
    }

    if (isFlowable) {
        return observable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
    }
    if (isSingle) {
        return observable.singleOrError();
    }
    if (isMaybe) {
        return observable.singleElement();
    }
    if (isCompletable) {
        return observable.ignoreElements();
    }
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(observable);
}
```

}
class OAuthCallAdapter implements CallAdapter<R, Object> {

```
private final Type responseType;
private final boolean isAsync;
private final boolean isBody;
private final boolean isFlowable;
private final boolean isSingle;
private final boolean isMaybe;
private final boolean isCompletable;
private final boolean ignoreAuth;

public OAuthCallAdapter(Type responseType, boolean isAsync, boolean isBody, boolean isFlowable, boolean isSingle, boolean isMaybe, boolean isCompletable, boolean ignoreAuth) {
    this.responseType = responseType;
    this.isAsync = isAsync;
    this.isBody = isBody;
    this.isFlowable = isFlowable;
    this.isSingle = isSingle;
    this.isMaybe = isMaybe;
    this.isCompletable = isCompletable;
    this.ignoreAuth = ignoreAuth;
}

@NotNull
@Override
public Type responseType() {
    return responseType;
}

@NotNull
@Override
public Object adapt(@NotNull Call<R> call) {
    Observable<Response<R>> responseObservable = isAsync
            ? new CallEnqueueObservable<>(call)
            : new CallExecuteObservable<>(call);

    Observable<?> observable;
    if (isBody) {
        observable = new BodyObservable<>(responseObservable);
    } else {
        observable = responseObservable;
    }

    if (!ignoreAuth) {
        observable = wrapWithOAuth(observable);
    }

    if (isFlowable) {
        return observable.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
    }
    if (isSingle) {
        return observable.singleOrError();
    }
    if (isMaybe) {
        return observable.singleElement();
    }
    if (isCompletable) {
        return observable.ignoreElements();
    }
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(observable);
}
```

}

And a custom error Handler to refresh tokens

```
class OAuthAuthenticationErrorHandler {

    public static boolean invalidAccessToken(Throwable throwable) {
        return throwable instanceof HttpException && ((HttpException) throwable).code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
    }

    public static boolean invalidRefreshToken(Throwable throwable) {
        if(throwable instanceof HttpException){
            return ((HttpException) throwable).code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST || ((HttpException) throwable).code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here my annotation class to exclude login points

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface AuthExempt {
}
```

With more experimenting, you could load some values from a Json file and populate the class

```
class RxOAuthUser {

private String client_id;
private String client_secret;
private String redirect_uri;
private String authorization_scope;
private String oAuthEndpoint;
private Long expirationTime;
private String refreshToken;
private String accessToken;
private String grantType;

RxOAuthUser(Context mContext) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = mContext.getAssets().open(mContext.getPackageName() + ".json");

        int size = inputStream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        if (inputStream.read(buffer) != size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        inputStream.close();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        client_id = jsonObject.getString("client_id");
        client_secret = jsonObject.getString("client_secret");
        redirect_uri = jsonObject.getString("redirect_uri");
        authorization_scope = jsonObject.getString("scope");
        oAuthEndpoint = jsonObject.getString("query_url");
        grantType = jsonObject.getString("grant_type");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This was heavily inspired by https://github.com/AckeeCZ/rxoauth - someone that is a lot smarter than me - So any feed back would be appreciated

Comment: thank you so much for fast response email can give a sample with real working ending points with authenticated sample

Comment: @EdgarDavids The classes above arecomplete. You would need to create a new Android App, add the classes etc.

I tested mine against the https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/basics-of-authentication/

You should do the same, it really helps with understanding and learning what is doing what 

https://oauth.net/2/ was also a great resource in understanding

Comment: TDIScott thank you for your valuable answer sure I will do as you told can I wrote some question to this comment I have any questions and I hope you are safe.